# htaccess stats for specific file type

Tags: php, .htaccess, statistics

Ive been looking all over but couldn't find anything so I am here to resort to my last hope resort :)

I am trying to create some type of page viewing statistics for only files of mine that end with swf.
I was wondering if its possible that htaccess can request the URL of another php file if the file extension they are going to ends in .swf but still land on the swf page.

I know i could easily use javascript with a link onclick function but this simply wont work for direct links/reefer's.

Comment: If you can use mod_rewrite you can make a rule that redirects all swf files to a php file. This php file will then do what ever you want, for example update a database with the views to a specific swf file and then gives out the swf file. I suppose you could rewrite a hotlinking prevention code to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't related to `.htaccess` because I don't think what you want to do is possible with `.htaccess` (But don't quote me on that)

You could make a PHP page like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash');    
$content = file_get_contents('swffile.swf');
echo $content;

// Stat tracking code here 

?>
```

Then you could send people directly to it and it would act like a .swf file. Since you'd be making a lot of calls to `file_get_contents('swffile.swf');` which reads the file of the hard disk you'd probably also want to look into something like [PHP Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php), so you could cache the contents of you .swf file in your servers RAM and significantly speed up the request time :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you could write a simple counter script that takes as a parameter the name of the .swf file.  Inside the script you would do whatever it is that you want to log it, and then return the proper header mime type for the swf, open it and return with fopen() etc.  This technique is often used to secure assets that need to be accessed after a login, and should not have a direct access url available.

Of course there is overhead in processing the file through php.

If you still want to do something like this, you simply need to create a rewrite rule that finds all files ending in .swf, and redirecting them to your script along with your url parameter based on the original .swf name.

Comment: Well it looks like Paul already provided more detail on the idea in his answer.